# Extracting a fragment from a string in PHP

Tags: php, string, text

Valid, and ONLY possible source string formats: (numbers and letters will vary)

1. xxxx/xxxx/0884/11  (x corresponds to random letters)
2. xxxx/xxxx/884/11    (x corresponds to random letters)
3. 884/11
4. 0884/11
5. 7/11

Desired outputs after extraction (respectively):

1. 0884
2. 0884
3. 0884
4. 0884
5. 0007

Can this be done a bit cleanly, with perhaps some regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blah :) the generic condition is: (`beginning of string` OR `characters than /`) and after that `1 to 4 numbers`, the precondition in PCRE is: `^|\w+/`, numbers are: `\d{1,4}`.

Joined together you will get this regexp: `~(^|\w+/)(\d{1,4})~` which can be used with [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) into this:

```
$match = array();
preg_match( '~(^|\w+/)(\d{1,4})~', $yourLine, $match);
// And pad it to left side with zeros:
$result = str_pad( $match[2], 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: Your regex matches the invalid formats as well. Examples are `foo/123`, `123/bar` or even `123` alone, with `123` being the match in each of them.

Comment: @rhino I know that... Fortunately: Valid, and *ONLY possible* source string formats; so I choose the simplest pattern I could think of